# c# Lambda AWS SNS(Notifications) - Unable to publish message to AWS SNS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, notifications, publish

I am unable to publish a message to AWS SNS(Notifications service) using a Lambda function. It works fine when i test it on my local machine but as soon as i deploy it to AWS Lambda, it hangs on "client.Publish(request);" It doesnt return with any result.

Please see code below.

```
namespace SendAWSNotifications
{
    public class Function
    {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Publish AWS notification message
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FunctionHandler(object input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.Log("Start");
            var awsKeyId = "AKI**********GOJ";
            var awsKeySecret = "nK9**************eQ8A";
            var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsKeyId, awsKeySecret);

            var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(awsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.AFSouth1);

            var request = new PublishRequest
            {
                TopicArn = "arn:aws:sns:af-south-1:***************:TestTopic",
                Message = "Test Message20"
            };

            context.Logger.Log("Send");
            var result = client.Publish(request);
            context.Logger.Log("Done");

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Lambda is probably running in a private VPC which does not have access to the SNS or the internet. For that you have to create a [Interface Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-vpc-tutorial.html) in order to be able to publish to SNS.  Also, please don't use secrets in your code, the Lambda has an execution role for which you can add permissions to publish to the SNS topic.

Comment: Is your AWS Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is there a particular reason _why_ it is connected to a VPC? If not, try disconnecting it and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Yes, it is in a VPC. Will try to add a Endpoint

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I removed the VPC and now it is working,Thanks!

Comment: Oh...just realized now why i added to the VPC, i must connect to our RDS Postgres database. so i will have to follow @ErvinSzilagyi route of creating a Endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The API endpoint for Amazon SNS is on the Internet. It seems like your Lambda function is unable reach the Internet.

AWS Lambda functions that are connected to a VPC only receive Internet access if the Lambda function is connected to a private subnet and there is a NAT Gateway in a public subnet.

AWS Lambda functions that are *not* connected to a VPC automatically have Internet access.